# Why does diethylmethylamine have such a low melting point?

Tags: phase, intermolecular-forces, melting-point

[According to PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Diethylmethylamine#section=Melting-Point), diethylmethylamine has a remarkably low melting point of $-196.0\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$. This is substantially lower than the melting points of [dimethylethylamine](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/11723#section=Melting-Point) ($-140.0\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$), [trimethylamine](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/1146#section=Melting-Point) ($-117.1\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$), [triethylamine](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/8471#section=Melting-Point) ($-114.7\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$), and [3-methylpentane](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/3-METHYLPENTANE#section=Melting-Point) (given as both $-162.9\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ and $-118\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$, not sure which is right). Why is that? Is diethylmethylamine uniquely ill-suited to forming a stable crystal lattice for some reason (maybe its highly asymmetric structure)?

Comment: As a small aside, diethylmethylamine is potentially the substance with the lowest melting point that remains liquid in ambient conditions. The value -196 °C is a little suspicious in that it happens to equal the boiling point for liquid nitrogen, so I hope it's not actually some kind of data misinterpretation.

Comment: The true melting point for diethylmethylamine is yet unknown; the original reference for this "melting point" value is J. Org. Chem. 22, 840-843 (1957), which states that the material became a glass at liquid nitrogen temperature. Also of interest is that the same exact data points are given for isopropyldimethylamine and diisopropylmethylamine, but have apparently never been misconstrued as melting points for those compounds!